# SharePoint 2007 - How to list all the features for all the site collections and their subsites?

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell

We are migrating a farm from 2007 to 2013 and for records we need to list features for all the site collections and their subsites under a web application with their status (Activated\Deactivated). We need something as following table.

URL|Feature Name|GUID|Status

It has powershell 1.0 and STSADM.
It does not have SharePoint snappin.

It would be really helpful if I could get a fully built script for the same.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would just be for a single site collection, but the script can be built out to expose the properties of each feature and loop through all site collections:

```
$site = Get-SPSite -Identity [YOUR SITE URL]
$features = $site.Features
Out-File E:\features.txt
foreach ($feature in $features) {
    $feature | Out-File E:\features.txt -Append
}
```